# Scala vs F# on List range from 1 to 100000000

Tags: list, scala, f#

I have written a list manipulation function both on F# and Scala to compare the performance.  To test that function I need to initialize a List from 1 to 100000000.

**F#:**

```
let l = [1..100000000];;
```

Real: 00:00:32.954, CPU: 00:00:34.593, GC gen0: 1030, gen1: 520, gen2: 9

This works.

**Scala:**
Scala -J-Xmx2G option

```
val l = (1 to 10000000).toList // works

val l = (1 to 100000000).toList // no response long while and finally got java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

With 100000000 (100,000,000), no response for a long while (an hour) with 75% to 90% CPU utilization and 2GB memory utilization and finally got 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

Am I doing anything wrong in Scala?

Comment: Do you try increment memory? Probably when you generate list garbage collector run process and use 90% of your CPU.

Comment: There is tons of overhead in a scala `List` for so many elements. You're not doing anything wrong; it's just a lot of object allocation. The only collection I can construct of that size in reasonable time appears to be an Array.

Comment: Is the F# heap size similarly restricted to 2GB? The list itself, assuming 8 byte integers and 8 byte pointers, takes up at least 1.6GB of heap memory.

Comment: @lea, it is not necessary for CLR to setup heap size for cases like the above.  With its default, F# works well.

Comment: @Nate, with -J-Xmx2G, Array works..but my manipulation function struggles.  Let me analyze in detail and let you know the result.

Answer (score 5):

Note that `val l = (1 to 100000000).toList` creates a new `List` with contents from the original `Range` `(1 to 100000000)`, hence a chance for a shortage in the heap space, as well as heavy triggering of the garbage collector. Increase `-J-Xmx` as @krynio suggested.

Yet without modifying the heap size, consider the use of iterators, especially if the performance test relies on a sequential iteration over the list; like this

```
(1 to 100000000).iterator
res0: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator
```

Comment: Thanks @enzyme.  Actually, I have used `-J-Xmx2G` for the above case.  And the list manipulation function relies on head and tail feature of List, particularly `+:` prepend operator.